# Spring Session the cookie never expires

Tags: java, spring-session

I recently implement Spring Session.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I make my own implementation of the sessionRepository, so when the session is created I configure the setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds with 60 seconds. If I debug this code the session object has the correct max inactive interval, but If I wait on the website without make anything, the session never expires.

Any idea to fix this?
Thanks

```
public class SpringSessionRepository implements SessionRepository<ExpiringSession> {
    @Override
    public ExpiringSession createSession() {
        ExpiringSession result = new MapSession();     

        result.setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds(60);

        return result;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of spring session doesn't support expiration configuration.

Here is the issue on github:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/106